# MsBuild Runner error - sonar.cs.fxcop assembly must be set

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

Updated - Using the MSbuild Runner, we see the following error

We have set the property in sonar.project.properties
sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe

[image]

C# Plugin - 4.1
MsBuild Runner - 1.0
SonarQube - 5.1.1

Comment: Could you please provide some more info, such as the SonarQube and plugin versions you are using? Moreover, it seems that you are using the sonar-runner, whereas the MSBuild SonarQube Runner is now the recommended way to analyze .NET projects. `sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern` is deprecated as all other `sonar.dotnet.*` properties. `sonar.opencover.installDirectory` is no longer supported.

Comment: version - 5.1.1, C# - 4.0, visualstudio - 1.2 . Will try using MSBuild.. Removed the deprecated dotnet configs..   I have a valid coverage xml from opencover & VS2013..  tried the opencover config as well.. What else should I be checking?

Answer (score 0):

You will find complete end-to-end examples on how to run OpenCover (and all the other supported coverage tools) with the MSBuild SonarQube Runner in the official documentation: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Code+Coverage+Results+Import